# How to compare and get items in List<T> base on object type

Tags: c#, list

Hi guys I have 2 different List 1 that holds items that I see as a requirements and the other one is user provided. I need to check all the List passed on to me against my List and get all items that the user failed to include. The checking is based on item class type. Is there any way I can do this without looping on my list and comparing one by one?

EDIT:
By the way I'm still using .net 2.0 which no Lambda expression yet.

EDIT 2:
Thanks for the answer. I guess I'm stuck on looping with it but found some pretty nice way to make it far better than the old one does.

Comment: Post examples of both lists and if you have example code of you how do it with looping, then people can help you optimize with less looping or hidden looping (but no, you can't do it totally without looping through the lists).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I'm in *full* understanding of what you're asking, but I *think* you have a list of types and then a list of objects and you want to see what types are missing in the list of objects. Is that correct? If so, you may be searching for something like this

```
List<Type> types = new List<Type>() { typeof(int), typeof(double), typeof(float) };
List<object> objects = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3, 2d, 4d };

var missingTypes = types.Except(objects.Select(obj => obj.GetType()));
```

Which, in this case, would result in a sequence that simply contains the type for `float`. By using LINQ, you are looping but it is abstracted away.

**Edit:** In .NET 2.0, you can do something like the following to get your missing types. You're still looping, but it's not too bad. You might be able to write this better, and you could certainly write it better in 3.5+ (even without LINQ), but it should get you started.

```
static IEnumerable<Type> GetMissingTypes(IEnumerable<Type> types, List<object> objects)
{
    List<Type> existingTypes = objects.ConvertAll(delegate(object obj) { return obj.GetType(); });
    foreach (Type type in types)
    {
        if (!existingTypes.Contains(type))
            yield return type;
    }
}

// ...

List<Type> types = new List<Type>() { typeof(int), typeof(double), typeof(float) };
List<object> objects = new List<object>() { 1, 2, 3, 2d, 4d };
IEnumerable<Type> missingTypes = GetMissingTypes(types, objects);
```

Comment: I'm  using still using 2.0 and no Lambda expression yet. Is there any way I can do this on my current framework?

Comment: Thanks for the help Anthony!. Got some pretty good ideas on how things can be done without LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IEnumerable.Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) like this:

```
requirements.Except(userProvided,
    delegate (T req, T user)
    {
        req.GetType().Equals(user.GetType());
    });
```

Comment: This extension method isn't available in .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Stuck looping regardless. Syntatical sugar or not, either its a loop in code or a loop by the compiler.

jtdubs is on the right track, only using a method outside of 2.0. Cycle through either collection and use a delegate as a Predicate to [Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx) instances in the other. Not the prettiest but 2.0 was pretty clunky when dealing with collection manipulation. It is what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than looping, you could do a sort and then compare. Without any code samples from you we can all just keep guessing though. Can you use your "item class type" as a string? If so a sort and compare will be much faster and you won't be looping either.

How many items in a list are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

In preparing you for Linq, consider the following

```
string[] reqs = { "A", "C", "E", "Z" };

string[] list = { "A", "E", "Z", "C" };

string[] unmet = Array.FindAll(reqs,
    delegate(string item)
    {
        return !Array.Exists(list, item.Equals);
    });

bool all_done = unmet.Length == 0;
```

where `reqs` is the requirements and `list` is the user supplied items. The `Array` class has many static methods for handing arrays pre-linq. Use them as they are a life saver in .NET 2.0

The `unmet` array will tell you what is missing.